# show animation and locking the current view

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiactivityindicatorview

I have a method which is calling a external webservice.
Now I want to show an `UIActivityIndicatorView` in the middle of the screen, while the webservice-call is running. I call the webservice-method asynchronously. But with my code which you will find at the bottom, I have two problems:

1. the current view is not locked. That means, that the user can interact with the current view. I want to block all till the animation is stopped
2. the animation is not centered

Here is my code which I have tried now:

```
-(void)saveDataOnServer {
    UIActivityIndicatorView *activity = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(225, 115, 30, 30)];
    [activity setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    [activity setActivityIndicatorViewStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray];
    [self.view addSubview:activity];
    [activity startAnimating];

    // ...     

    [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest: request
                                       queue: queue
                           completionHandler: ^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error) {

                               [activity stopAnimating];

                               // ...
                           }
     ];
}
```

Comment: [self.view setUserInteractionEnabled:NO]; set this to lock interaction with View. Animation is not centered then check your Frame adjust that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to put another view when activity indicator start :

```
 UIView *overlayView;
 overlayView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds];
 overlayView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0 green:0 blue:0 alpha:0.5];
 [[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow addSubview:overlayView];
```

And remove that view(overlayView) when activity indicator stops :

```
 [overlayView removeFromSuperview];
```

This OverlayView will cover current view.So user can not interact with current view.

Answer (score 0):

Hi there i have a good solution for you ..
there i a library called MBProgressHUD
which does all you want , WITH Style 
This is The link for the library [HERE](https://github.com/jdg/MBProgressHUD)

And its easy to use .. here is an example i used

```
self.hud = [MBProgressHUD showHUDAddedTo:self.view animated:YES];
self.hud.mode = MBProgressHUDModeIndeterminate;
self.hud.labelText = @"Fetching News";
//self.hud.detailsLabelText=@"Fetching News";
self.hud.dimBackground = YES;
```

and there  is a demo you can see .. Cheers :D

Comment: thank you - thats great! One more question: How can I stop the hud?

Comment: simpley use `[self.hud hide:YES];`